# Print date of last Tuesday of each month of next year using Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

How can I print the date of the last Tuesday of each month for next year using Python.

For example the first line outputted would be: 30/Jan/2018

I do not want to have the full name of the month only the first 3 characters!

Currently I have figured out how to get the next year:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
next_year = now.year + 1
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module is perfect for this:

You can use [calendar.**month_abbr**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_abbr) which is an array of
   abbreviated months just like you want.

`week` is an array representing the days of the week starting at Monday so Tuesday would be `week[1]`.

```
import calendar
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
next_year = now.year + 1

for month in range(1, 13):
    last_tuesday = max(week[1] for week in calendar.monthcalendar(next_year, month))
    print('{}/{}/{}'.format(last_tuesday, calendar.month_abbr[month], next_year))
```

**Output:**

```
30/Jan/2018
27/Feb/2018
27/Mar/2018
24/Apr/2018
29/May/2018
26/Jun/2018
31/Jul/2018
28/Aug/2018
25/Sep/2018
30/Oct/2018
27/Nov/2018
25/Dec/2018
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest the pandas DateOffset object `LastWeekOfMonth`.

> Describes monthly dates in last week of month like "the last Tuesday
>   of each month"

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import LastWeekOfMonth

def last_tues(year):
    return (pd.date_range('1/1/' + str(year), periods=12, freq='M')
           - LastWeekOfMonth(n=1, weekday=1)).strftime('%d/%b/%Y'))

last_tues(2018)
Out[31]: 
array(['30/Jan/2018', '27/Feb/2018', '27/Mar/2018', '24/Apr/2018',
       '29/May/2018', '26/Jun/2018', '26/Jun/2018', '28/Aug/2018',
       '25/Sep/2018', '30/Oct/2018', '27/Nov/2018', '25/Dec/2018'], 
      dtype='<U11')
```